# Install two times maven in WINDOWS meachine

Tags: java, maven

I am working with `maven` + `java`

Here I want to install Two times maven in My meachine

```
1> Actual Development with its own .m2 repository
2> Learing Technologies with its own .m2 repositroy
```

Help me how to Do this ?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this, as it defeats the whole purpose of dependency management. You shouldn't care whats in the repo so much as you care what libraries you define in each of your projects POM files. They can coexist together just fine.

Comment: why do you want to have two repositories? you can have maven installation and still point to single repository.

Comment: i dont want disturb the my development repository.

Comment: @Pradeep Keeping same repo doesn't disturb anything in your project. If you want a fresh repo and want the project build to download all binaries from internet in development build, just delete the contents of `.m2` directory completely before running the maven commands. The libraries will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

No sure why you want to do this as already others commented out.

You can use the <localRepository/> to specify where the repository is.
So you can change this value for your needs.

See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/settings.html